# Lean "nonempty" vs "inhabited"

Tags: lean, lean3

In the init/logic.lean file of the Lean 3 standard library, `nonempty` and `inhabited` are defined. It seems like these two classes are very similar - you can instantiate either of them given an element of the type. In what situations do you use one over the other?

Comment: I find the Lean terminology confusing. In my world it is: `nonempty A` means $A \to \emptyset$; `inhabited A` means $\exists x \in A  . \top$; and `pointed` means $\Sigma_{A : \mathsf{Type}} A$, or in fibered form `pointed A` means $A$.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer, Lean calls $A → ∅$ [`is_empty A`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/logic/is_empty.html#is_empty), which seems like the opposite of the meaning you're suggesting. Do you really use "nonempty" to mean "has no elements"?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that, I've just returned from England. I should have $(A \to \emptyset) \to \emptyset$, or equivalently $\neg\neg \exists x \in A . \top$.

Comment: @Guy Coder: the relevant lines of the files you link to (both Lean 3, just different versions of it) are equivalent if not identical, so the distinction isn't important.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The difference between [`Nonempty`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/find/?pattern=Nonempty#doc) and [`Inhabited`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/find/?pattern=Nonempty#doc) is that `Nonempty A : Prop` but `Inhabited A : Sort (max 1 u)` (if `A : Sort u`). This makes `Inhabited A` isomorphic as a type to `A`, while `Nonempty A` is the propositional truncation of `A`, equivalent to `∃ x : A, True`. To extract a value from `Inhabited A` is [`Inhabited.default`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/find/?pattern=Inhabited.default#doc), but extracting a value from a proof of `Nonempty A` is the [axiom of choice](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/find/?pattern=Classical.choice#doc) and is `noncomputable`.

Generally, you should use `Nonempty A` if you only need the "mere fact" that `A` is not empty, while `Inhabited A` is used if you need to access a specific default value for totalizing a function or so. Mathlib has a linter to ensure that you don't use `Inhabited` in place of `Nonempty` for proving theorems unless you need it in the statement of the theorem.